# extension method for substring C#

Tags: c#, methods

When I write down the code below. I cannot choose my extension method.It doesn't appear. I can't seem to find my mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string MySubstring(
        this int index, int length)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        return sb.ToString(index, length);
    }
}

class SubstringExtension
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "I want to fly away.";
        string result = text.
    }
}
```

Comment: You are making a extension method for an `int` but trying to call it for a `string`

Comment: And the code for MySubstring makes no sense. What your extension method is supposed to do?

Comment: @Steve , was about to add that :-)

Comment: @Jcl I was writing about the int so I choose the other point :-)

Comment: My extension method is supposed to do the same thing as the usual Substring does

Comment: @codeAddicted The 'usual substring' doesn't try to operate on an `int`. Maybe if your's didn't either, it would get closer to what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want your extension method to be based on a `string`, so you need to make that string your `this` parameter in your extension method, like this:

```
void Main()
{
    string text = "I want to fly away.";
    string result = text.MySubstring(1, 5);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string MySubstring(
        this string str, int index, int length)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);

        return sb.ToString(index, length);
    }
}
```

Result:

> want

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked. :) I have a lot to learn...

Comment: @codeAddicted: I'm glad to help. Please mark the question answered so other people know you don't need help still. :-)